# Unpack a String and Arrange it Into Required Structure

Tags: c#

I am trying to read a string sent from a third party tool. They send a message which starts with `{` and ends with `}`. The fields in the message are separated by `*`. The first field is `MessageID`, followed by `Number of Data Fields` and the rest is data.

For example:

```
{14*2*57241*5684}
```

So `14` is the `MessageID`, `2` is the number of data fields and the data (2 fields) is `57241` and `5684`.

I made a structure for message

```
struct EMessage
{
    public MessageID ID;
    public byte length;
    public Int32[] data; // Int because the maximum size is 32 bit
}
```

and the function to read the message

```
EMessage unPackEMessage(string messageFromE)
{
        int strLength = messageFromE.Length;
        char[] a = new char[strLength];
        int i = 0;

        foreach (char ch in messageFromE)
        {
            a[i] = ch;
            i++;
        }

        EMessage theMessage = new EMessage();
        theMessage.ID = (MessageID)a[1];
        theMessage.length = (byte)a[3];
        int[] mData = new int[theMessage.length];
        // Please help here
        return theMessage;

    }
```

I am not able to get the data Part right. I cant split the remaining string and get data dumped into the data part of structure. Please help

Comment: dont use `foreach` with counter. thats whats `for` for!

Comment: also there is already split method for that. `messageFromE.Split(new[] {'*', '{', '}'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`. this gives you array of string splitted by `*`.

Comment: You would want to take off the `{` and `}` first, but `String.Split` is made for this..

Comment: Hi @M.kazemAkhgary Thanks, on another note, how do you get . You 'solved' my issue.

Comment: Hey, I was unaware of Split functionality. So I was think of Finding * by looping. But this is a whole lot easier. FYI, I am an Automotive guy. Far away from the world of Coding. The Only message I read till now was CAN(control area network) messages. So thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that:

```
  String source = "{14*2*57241*5684}";
  String[] items = source.Trim('{', '}').Split('*');

  EMessage result = new EMessage() {
    ID = (MessageID) items[0],  //TODO: convert String to MessageID type value here
    length = Byte.Parse(items[1]),
    data = items
      .Skip(2)
      .Select(item => int.Parse(item))
      .ToArray()
  };
```

Comment: clean solution and i like that variable data-part +1

Comment: I would probably still use `int.Parse` for length (count) also, though. Nothing much is gained by limiting the count to a byte. Also, it's unclear from OP's example if there might be other tokens *after* the last value which shouldn't be parsed (because the length information is redundant the way the message is formed now).